# ¿Por que no me funciona esta function de php?

Tags: php

tengo que hacer que al ingresar un valor por el parametro se multiplique con el iterador  hasta que ese resultado acumulado sea mayor a su valor elevado,el valor debe ser elevado por el mismo numero que ingreso, hice lo siguiente:

```
function encontrarValorMayorASuElevado($valor){

$valorElevado=pow($valor, $valor);
$continuar=false;
$i=1;
$resultado=0;
while($continuar){

 $i++;

 $valor=$valor*$i;

 if($valor>$valorElevado){
    $resultado=$valor;
    $continuar=true;
    break;
 }else{
    $continuar=false;
 }


}

return $solucion=$resultado;
```

}

y no logro entender que hice mal, por que me devuelve 0, cuando se supone que cuando la variable resultado ingresa al bucle deberia cambiar su valor pero no lo hace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero estas iniciando tu variable `$continuar` como `false`, por lo que nunca entrara en el `while` ademas puedes optimizar algunas cosas, como el if ya que siempre se ira al else y vas a volver a asignar el mismo valor a la variable $continuar, por lo que el codigo quedaria asi:

```
 function encontrarValorMayorASuElevado($valor){
    $valorElevado=pow($valor, $valor);
    $continuar=true;
    $i=1;
    $resultado=0;
    while($continuar){
     $i++;
     $valor=$valor*$i;
     if($valor>$valorElevado){
        $resultado=$valor;
        $continuar=false;
     }
    }
    return $resultado;
    }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias , era eso :D , cambie el valor de continuar a true , Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

inicialisaste $continuar = false, por lo tanto nunca va entrar en el while, inicializa $continuar = true;

Quedaria algo asi:

```
function encontrarValorMayorASuElevado($valor){
$valorElevado=pow($valor, $valor);
$continuar=true;
$i=1;
$resultado=0;
while($continuar){

    $i++;

    $valor=$valor*$i;

    if($valor>$valorElevado){
        $resultado=$valor;
        $continuar=true;
        break;
    }else{
        $continuar=false;
    }


}

return $solucion=$resultado;
```

}